# Draggable-DIV styling based on its position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to drag a div, changing its style during dragging:
if the dragged div has a "border-left" with a position < 50% of its container width, then only "border-left" is 8px; otherwise (if the dragged div has a "border-left" with a position > 50% of its container width) only "border-right" is 8px. This is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/7cvecq52).

**HTML code**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="draggable right">
        <span id="border_left_position_percentage"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**:

```
body {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 8px solid blue;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
#border_left_position_percentage {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript Code**:

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    if ($(".draggable").draggable()) {
        $(".right").css("cursor", "all-scroll");
    } else {
        $(".right").css("cursor", "normal");
    }

    $(".right").on('dragstart', function () {
        $(this).on("mousemove", function () {
            var percentuale = parseInt((($(this).position().left / $(this).parent().width()) * 100), 10);
            $("#border_left_position_percentage").html(percentuale + "%");

            if (percentuale < 50) {
                $(this).css({
                    "border-right": "none",
                    "border-left": "8px solid blue",
                    "border-radius": "0 10px 10px 0"
                });
                $("#border_left_position_percentage").css({
                    "float": "right",
                    "display": "block"
                });
            } else {
                $(this).css({
                    "border-right": "8px solid blue",
                    "border-left": "none",
                    "border-radius": "10px 0 0 10px"
                });
                $("#border_left_position_percentage").css({
                    "float": "left",
                    "display": "block"
                });
            }
        });
    }).on("dragstop", function () {
        var percentuale = parseInt((($(this).position().left / $(this).parent().width()) * 100), 10);

        if (percentuale < 50) {
            $(this).animate({
                "position": "absolute",
                "float": "left",
                "left": "0",
                "border-radius": "0 10px 10px 0"
            }, 2000, function () {
                // Animation complete.
                $("#border_left_position_percentage").css("display", "none");
            });
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                "position": "absolute",
                "float": "right",
                "right": "0",
                "border-radius": "10px 0 0 10px"
            }, 2000, function () {
                // Animation complete.
                $("#border_left_position_percentage").css("display", "none");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I want to display percentage of "border-left" position only during dragging, hiding it on "dragstop" (on release), binding "draggable-div" on the left or right border of its container, always basing on "border-left" position...

I don't know why but, in my demo, the "draggable-div" binds itself always on the left of container, also if percentage is >50%, and percentage is displayed on mouse over, also if I use "display: none;", after the release.

Thanks to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why jQuery doesn't animate it to the right.  But you can simulate the behavior by animating left by this amount:

```
$('body').width() - $(this).width() - 8
```

The number 8 accounts for the 8px border.

The reason the percentage reappears on mouse over is due to this code:

```
$(this).on("mousemove", function () {
  ...
  $("#border_left_position_percentage").css({
     ...
     "display": "block"
  });
```

Even though it's defined within the `dragstart` event, it gets attached to the element, so it's always triggered whenever the mouse moves over the element.

In my code, I've moved the `mousemove` event outside of the `dragstart` event, and I don't change the display CSS:

```
$('.right').on('mousemove', function() {
  var percentuale = parseInt((($(this).position().left / $(this).parent().width()) * 100), 10);
  $("#border_left_position_percentage").html(percentuale + "%");
});
```

I've also moved the logic/CSS of your `mousemove` event to the `dragstop` event.

The `dragstart` event is now simply:

```
$('#border_left_position_percentage').css('display','block');
$(this).stop();
```

This shows the element, which then gets updated while dragging due to the `mousemove` event.  It also stops any animations in progress, so you can grab the box while it's moving.

### Fiddle

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and help! Using a different jQuery version is the same thing... Have you any idea for why also percentage is shown on mouseover the draggable div, at the end of animation (maybe, something like a refresh is also necessary, to update border-radius)?

Thanks so much,
Riccardo

Comment: Is this what you're going for?  http://jsfiddle.net/z5qb2mae/2/  If so, I'll update my answer with explanation.

Comment: Thanks Rick!
Yes, the effect is that! I updated the demo in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/7cvecq52/ Strange only the behavior when div floats on the right, but it's ok now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
"left": $('body').width() - $(this).width() - 8,
```

is possible to use:

```
'left': $('body').width() - $(this).outerWidth(true),
```

"**true**" to include also horizontal margins ([resource](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/)).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/7cvecq52/)